# Nul pointer Exception when setting the ImageAdapter from Async task - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to fetch data from movieDatabaseApi and display it in a GridView using Picasso library.
Using AsyncTask I've managed to get the urls I need(I can see them in a log).
From this point I am lost.

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] arrayList) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,arrayList[0]);

        mImageAdapter  = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
    }
```

I've changed my ImageAdapter to accept this array as an argument,but trying to set adapter to gridView from this location gives me NullPointerException. Even if I manage to attach a new adapter what is the next step? How do I access this Array in adapter?
This is my current code for Adapter:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] resultingArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, String[] arrayList) {
        mContext = c;
        resultingArray = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultingArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        String url="zero";
        url = resultingArray[position];
        Log.v("check urls",url);
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(imageView);
        return imageView;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your full code so that we will know what you have done it wrong.

Comment: Add `yourGridView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);` after `mImageAdapter  = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);`. Also you need to inflate your GridView item in `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Not Inflating any Grid Item to Display Image..Create a Custom Adapter with its Own ItemLayout

Have a look at this

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html